# Travelling through a for loop at the same time as deleting and inserting

Tags: algorithm, logic, simulation

I am writing a predator/prey simulation where objects can be born or killed. When killed, they are deleted from the arraylist, when born they are added. Each object in the list can kill another object or replicate. I travel through the list simulating each objects movement and interaction with the surroundings including the decision to replicate or kill another object if its close.

A normal for loop breaks as if a deletion or a birth occurs the index it is currently on is skewed.
What would be a better solution? While with a counter and conditional that the size > 0 or some other way?

Comment: use an `iterator`, and keep iterating `while (iter.hasNext())`? or are you looking for a solution that doesn't invoke the dupes at the end in the same iteration?

Comment: for births yes otherwise I can sometimes enter an infinite loop. For deaths, it has to be removed from the list so that it does not affect other objects

Comment: You can handle deaths by iterating backwards, then the current index does not change. I don't really see a way to handle both deaths and clones in a single pass though..

Comment: I had it working in javascript: http://deeplogic.info/draft/ albeit with quite a few errors, but when rewriting it in java It just wouldn't work the same way.

Answer (score 5):

You could wait until after you are finished iterating to add/remove items:

```
entities_to_add = new Array;
entities_to_remove = new Array;

function tick():
    for each entity in world:
        //general entity behavior goes here
        if entity.wants_to_reproduce:
            entities_to_add.append(entity.make_baby())
        if entity.wants_to_die:
            entities_to_remove.append(entity)

function cleanup():
    for each entity in entities_to_remove:
        world.remove(entity)
    for each entity in entities_to_add:
        world.add(entity)
    entities_to_remove.clear()
    entities_to_add.clear()

function main():
    while(True):
        tick()
        cleanup()
```

This has a disadvantage that an entity that dies will appear to remain alive until the end of the tick. This may be bad, for example if a predator kills a prey, and a second predator also kills that prey during the same tick. If that isn't desirable, you could make the predators check the entities_to_remove array before attacking to make sure their prey is still alive.

Comment: An improvement, which doesn't require an extra array, would be to use a flag: `IsAlive`. If a predator kills the prey, then the prey's `IsAlive` flag is set to `false`. The first iteration would mark the ones that are no longer alive and the second iteration would remove them.

Comment: For removing the items this will not work, but I may end up doing this for new additions.

Answer (score 1):

It is common in simulation to have two copies of the world - one for the state at time *t*, one for the state at time *t+Δt*.

If you don't have two copies, and try to birth entities as you process the state transition, then the first entity in the list will see a different world from the last.

For example, if more prey is birthed than felled in a tick, then predators who happen to be at the end of the list will have an advantage which is not part of the world being simulated, but an artefact of your implementation. If you've added 'red cats' and then 'blue cats', then the blue cats will do better, without there being any real difference.

If you do have two copies, then you have to resolve the issue of more than one predator felling the same prey, but your original problem won't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<Object> predators = new ArrayList<Object>();
    ArrayList<Object> preys = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (Object predator : predators) {
      Object[] entities = preys.toArray();
      for (Object entity : entities) {
        if (entity.shouldReprodue()) {
            world.add(entity.baby());
        }
        if (entity.shouldDie()) {
            world.remove(entity);
        }
      }
    }
```

I think every predator should make a new copy of the current world ArrayList.

Comment: Im sorry, but in a simple case this may have worked but with my scenario all the entities (bacteria) have to communicate with each other.